# How performant is Python's pattern matching? Is it O(1)?

Tags: python, performance, pattern-matching

As we know, Python will support [pattern matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/) in 3.10. Putting usage and syntax aside, I can't seem to find any word about performance in the PEP, or the [official tutorial](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/).

So I'm wondering, how performant is it? Is it O(1) or the same as `if..elif..else`?

Comment: The run time performance is going to depend on the pattern.

Comment: From [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#patterns-and-shapes) : *A `match` statement compares a value (the subject) to several different shapes (the patterns) **until a shape fits**.* It implies that it is a O(n) behavior like if-statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In terms of time complexity alone, the two constructs are basically equivalent.

They're very different, though, when considering readability and code structure. As a general rule, if you're matching *values* or testing several subjects, an `if`-`elif`-`else` ladder will probably be the best tool for the job:

```py
def stringify_response(response: int) -> str:
    if 100 <= response < 200:
        kind = "info"
    elif 200 <= response < 300:
        kind = "success"
    elif 300 <= response < 400:
        kind = "redirect"
    elif 400 <= response < 500:
        kind = "client error"
    elif 500 <= response < 600:
        kind = "server error"
    else:
        kind = "unexpected response"
    return f"{kind} ({response})"
```

On the other hand, if you're matching the *structure* of a single subject, then *structural* pattern matching will probably be the best tool for the job:

```py
from ast import *

def lint_function_def(function_def: FunctionDef) -> None:
    match function_def.body:
        case *_, Assign([Name(na)], e), Return(Name(nr, lineno=l)) if na == nr:
            print(f"line {l}: consider returning {unparse(e)} instead of "
                  f"assigning to {na!r} on line {e.lineno}")
```

## Future Improvements

With that said, one of the benefits of syntactical support for pattern matching is that the compiler and interpreter possess an extraordinary knowledge of context. Because of this, they can make assumptions that ordinary control flow cannot.

Consider this statement (slightly simplified) from [PEP 636](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/):

```py
match command.split():
    case ["north"] | ["go", "north"]:
        # Code for moving north.
    case ["get", obj] | ["pick", "up", obj] | ["pick", obj, "up"]:
        # Code for picking up the given object.
```

The "current" (CPython 3.10) pattern compiler is quite naive, and compiles it to something like this:

```py
_subject = command.split()
import _collections_abc
if (
    isinstance(_subject, _collections_abc.Sequence)
    and len(_subject) == 1
    and _subject[0] == "north"
):
    # Code for moving north.
elif (
    isinstance(_subject, _collections_abc.Sequence)
    and len(_subject) == 2
    and _subject[0] == "go"
    and _subject[1] == "north"
):
    # Code for moving north.
elif (
    isinstance(_subject, _collections_abc.Sequence)
    and len(_subject) == 2
    and _subject[0] == "get"
):
    obj = _subject[1]
    # Code for picking up the given object.
elif (
    isinstance(_subject, _collections_abc.Sequence)
    and len(_subject) == 3
    and _subject[0] == "pick"
    and _subject[1] == "up"
):
    obj = _subject[2]
    # Code for picking up the given object.
elif (
    isinstance(_subject, _collections_abc.Sequence)
    and len(_subject) == 3
    and _subject[0] == "pick"
    and _subject[2] == "up"
):
    obj = _subject[1]
    # Code for picking up the given object.
```

Even though this example is quite simple, the generated code is full of redundant checks. Matching the command `"pick Spam up"` checks `isinstance(_subject, _collections_abc.Sequence)` five times, calls `len(_subject)` five times, and checks `_subject[0] == "pick"` twice!

However, it's entirely possible for the compiler to generate more efficient "decision trees" instead, where no unnecessary work is performed. Here's what that might look like:

```py
_subject = command.split()
import _collections_abc
if isinstance(_subject, _collections_abc.Sequence):
    _len_subject = len(_subject)
    if _len_subject == 1:
        if _subject[0] == "north":
            # Code for moving north.
    elif _len_subject == 2:
        _subject_0 = _subject[0]
        if _subject_0 == "go":
            if _subject[1] == "north":
                # Code for moving north.
        elif _subject_0 == "get":
            obj = _subject[1]
            # Code for picking up the given object.
    elif _len_subject == 3:
        if _subject[0] == "pick":
            _subject_1 = _subject[1]
            if _subject_1 == "up":
                obj = _subject[2]
                # Code for picking up the given object.
            elif _subject[2] == "up":
                obj = _subject_1
                # Code for picking up the given object.
```

It starts getting more complicated when you have guards or nested patterns... but I'm hopeful that we'll be able to get something like this into CPython 3.11!

Comment: Thanks Brandt. Do you want to briefly describe the potential future improvements (decision tree) you mentioned before?

Comment: Sure @laike9m! I've added a section on possible future improvements.

Answer (score 5):

Pattern matching desugars into chained elif statements and isinsance calls. It's definitely not O(1) or close to any kind of lookup table.

Edit: More precisely, in the [merged pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/22917/files/69fa421115525c868520ffe37086b93169cf4e83#diff-c22186367cbe20233e843261998dc027ae5f1f8c0d2e778abfa454ae74cc59de), you can see that the `match` statement is turned into a chain of opcodes responsible for handling the various patterns. These opcodes are processed in sequence, much like chained `elif` statements.

Comment: Where can we read that (other than in this claim of yours)?